# RxJava Multiple Network Requests with replay

Tags: android, retrofit2, rx-java2

I have two API calls. The first API call returns a list of the most recent orders made with the order date and status. The second network call uses the unique id in the first call to return information about the order. 
I have the following:

```
public interface ServiceAPI
{
    @POST("buyer/recentOrders")
    Single<RecentOrdersJSON> getRecentOrders ();

    @POST("buyer/orderDetails/{ORDER_ID}")
    Single<OrderDetailsJSON> orderDetails(
            @Path("ORDER_ID") String ORDER_ID);
}
```

The RecentOrdersJSON Class:

```
public class RecentOrdersJSON {

    @SerializedName("orders")
    @Expose
    private List<Order> orders = null;
    @SerializedName("recordCount")
    @Expose
    private Integer recordCount;
    @SerializedName("msg")
    @Expose
    private String msg;
    @SerializedName("currency_symbol")
    @Expose
    private String currency_symbol;
    @SerializedName("status")
    @Expose
    private Integer status;

    public List<Order> getOrders() {
        return orders;
    }

    public void setOrders(List<Order> orders) {
        this.orders = orders;
    }

    public Integer getRecordCount() {
        return recordCount;
    }

    public void setRecordCount(Integer recordCount) {
        this.recordCount = recordCount;
    }

    public String getMsg() {
        return msg;
    }

    public void setMsg(String msg) {
        this.msg = msg;
    }

    public String getCurrency_symbol() {
        return currency_symbol;
    }

    public void setCurrency_symbol(String currency_symbol) {
        this.currency_symbol = currency_symbol;
    }

    public Integer getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(Integer status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

}
```

The OrderDetailsJSON class:

```
public class OrderDetailsJSON {

    @SerializedName("productDetails")
    @Expose
    private List<ProductDetail> productDetails = null;
    @SerializedName("orderStatusHistory")
    @Expose
    private List<OrderStatusHistory> orderStatusHistory = null;
    @SerializedName("orderInfo")
    @Expose
    private OrderInfo orderInfo;
    @SerializedName("billingAddress")
    @Expose
    private BillingAddress billingAddress;
    @SerializedName("unreadNotificationCount")
    @Expose
    private Integer unreadNotificationCount;
    @SerializedName("msg")
    @Expose
    private String msg;
    @SerializedName("currency_symbol")
    @Expose
    private String currency_symbol;
    @SerializedName("status")
    @Expose
    private Integer status;

    public List<ProductDetail> getProductDetails() {
        return productDetails;
    }

    public void setProductDetails(List<ProductDetail> productDetails) {
        this.productDetails = productDetails;
    }

    public List<OrderStatusHistory> getOrderStatusHistory() {
        return orderStatusHistory;
    }

    public void setOrderStatusHistory(List<OrderStatusHistory> orderStatusHistory) {
        this.orderStatusHistory = orderStatusHistory;
    }

    public OrderInfo getOrderInfo() {
        return orderInfo;
    }

    public void setOrderInfo(OrderInfo orderInfo) {
        this.orderInfo = orderInfo;
    }

    public BillingAddress getBillingAddress() {
        return billingAddress;
    }

    public void setBillingAddress(BillingAddress billingAddress) {
        this.billingAddress = billingAddress;
    }

    public Integer getUnreadNotificationCount() {
        return unreadNotificationCount;
    }

    public void setUnreadNotificationCount(Integer unreadNotificationCount) {
        this.unreadNotificationCount = unreadNotificationCount;
    }

    public String getMsg() {
        return msg;
    }

    public void setMsg(String msg) {
        this.msg = msg;
    }

    public String getCurrency_symbol() {
        return currency_symbol;
    }

    public void setCurrency_symbol(String currency_symbol) {
        this.currency_symbol = currency_symbol;
    }

    public Integer getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(Integer status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

}

private Observable<RecentOrdersJSON> getOrders()
{
    return ServiceAPI.getRecentOrders()
            .toObservable()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
}


ConnectableObservable<RecentOrdersJSON> ordersObservable = (ConnectableObservable<RecentOrdersJSON>) getOrders().replay();

disposable.add(
        ordersObservable
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribeWith(new DisposableObserver<RecentOrdersJSON>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onNext(RecentOrdersJSON recentOrdersJSON)
                    {

                        // Refreshing List
                        orderList.clear();
                        orderList.addAll(recentOrdersJSON.getOrders());
                        orderlistAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e)
                    {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete()
                    {

                    }
                }));


// Fetching individual orderInfo
disposable.add(ordersObservable
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())

                .flatMap(new Function<List<Order>, ObservableSource<Order>>()
               {
                  @Override
                    public ObservableSource<Order> apply(List<Order> orders)
                   {
                                                   return Observable.fromIterable(orders);
                    }
               })

);


private Observable<OrderDetailsJSON> getOrderObservable(final String Order_ID)
{
    return ServiceAPI.orderDetails(Order_ID)
            .toObservable()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());

}
```

The Order POJO:

```
   @SerializedName("order_id")
    @Expose
    private String order_id;
    @SerializedName("order_date_added")
    @Expose
    private String order_date_added;
    @SerializedName("order_status")
    @Expose
    private Integer order_status;

    public String getOrder_id() {
        return order_id;
    }

    public void setOrder_id(String order_id) {
        this.order_id = order_id;
    }

    public String getOrder_date_added() {
        return order_date_added;
    }

    public void setOrder_date_added(String order_date_added) {
        this.order_date_added = order_date_added;
    }

    public Integer getOrder_status() {
        return order_status;
    }

    public void setOrder_status(Integer order_status) {
        this.order_status = order_status;
    }
```

When trying to use a flatmap to get the id from the first network call result I get the following message Observable cannot be applied.

Comment: Are you trying to flat map a single to an observable? This won't work. Try `flatMapObservable`.

Comment: @Fred, flatMapObservable cannot be resolved.

Comment: Ok, I'm confused, what are you trying to do? `getOrders().flatMap(order -> getOrderObservable(order.getId())`?

Comment: @ Fred I'm not well versed with using RxJava I'm learning as I go. What I am trying to do is I want to get the orders list from the orders observable, get each of   id's from the list and replay the network call with the ids to get back a list of order information for those id's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all :

Your Order pojo need to have OrderDetailsJSON object

```sh
public class Order {

   ...

   OrderDetailsJSON orderDetailsJson;

   public void setOrderDetailsJson(OrderDetailsJSON orderDetailsJson) {
      this.orderDetailsJson = orderDetailsJson;
   }

   public OrderDetailsJSON getOrderDetailsJson(){
      return this.orderDetailsJson
   }
}
```

**The replay**

replay() operator is used to make an Observable emit the data on new subscriptions without re-executing the logic again i.e. without making the api call again(getOrders().replay()). Since you are using ConnectableObservable make following changes in you implementation to achieve what you want ...

> Replace this

```sh
// Fetching individual orderInfo
disposable.add(ordersObservable
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())

                .flatMap(new Function<List<Order>, ObservableSource<Order>>()
               {
                  @Override
                    public ObservableSource<Order> apply(List<Order> orders)
                   {
                                                   return Observable.fromIterable(orders);
                    }
               })

);
```

> with

```sh
/**
 * Fetching individual order details
 * First FlatMap converts single List<Order> from RecentOrdersJSON to multiple emissions of orders
 * Second FlatMap makes HTTP call on each Order emission to fetch the details
 * */
disposable.add(
        ordersObservable
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            /**
             * Converting List<Order> emission to single Order emissions
             * */
            .flatMap(new Function<RecentOrdersJSON, ObservableSource<Order>>() {
                @Override
                public ObservableSource<Order> apply(RecentOrdersJSON recentOrderJson)
                {
                    return Observable.fromIterable(recentOrdersJSON.getOrders());
                }
            })
            /**
             * Fetching details on each order emission
             * */
            .flatMap(new Function<Order, ObservableSource<Order>>() {
                @Override
                public ObservableSource<Order> apply(Order order) throws Exception {
                    return getOrderDetailsObservable(order);
                }
            })
            .subscribeWith(new DisposableObserver<Order>() {

                @Override
                public void onNext(Order order) {
                    int position = orderList.indexOf(order);

                    if (position == -1) {
                        // Order not found in the list
                        // This shouldn't happen
                        return;
                    }

                    orderList.set(position, order);
                    orderlistAdapter.notifyItemChanged(position);
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    //show error
                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {

                }
}));
```

> Also replace this

```sh
private Observable<OrderDetailsJSON> getOrderObservable(final String Order_ID)
{ 
    return ServiceAPI.orderDetails(Order_ID)
            .toObservable() 
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()) 
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()); 

}
```

> with

```sh
private Observable<Order> getOrderDetailsObservable(final Order order) {
    return ServiceAPI
            .orderDetails(order.getOrder_id())
            .toObservable()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .map(new Function<OrderDetailsJSON, Order>() {
                @Override
                public Order apply(OrderDetailsJSON orderDetailsJSON) throws Exception {
                    order.setOrderDetailsJson(orderDetailsJSON);
                    return order;
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: are you saying I should change my current order POJO. See the edited question I have included it.

Comment: Yes you will be needing OrderDetailsJSON inside the Order POJO, that will be used to map each Order object with its OrderDetailsJSON, refer to getOrderDetailsObservable(final Order order) where the mapping is performed. Then you can use OrderDetailsJSON properties inside your recycler adapter from orderList itself.

Comment: .flatMap(new Function<RecentOrdersJSON, ObservableSource<Ticket>>()  Ticket ?

Comment: Edited.It was a mistake.

Comment: Have made few more changes in the call and definition of getOrderDetailsObservable(order). Do let me know if this works for you.

Comment: I am just testing it out right now quick question is this your blog https://www.androidhive.info/RxJava/tutorials/

Comment: Nope, but I had followed the same for my own purpose and spices previously. It is written by RAVI TAMADA, great open source knowledge contributor. I should give credit as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187741/discussion-between-george-and-suyash-chavan).